# Splitting bars in ggplot2

Tags: r

I'm super new at this and starting in the middle while working forwards and backwards simultaneously, so forgive me if this is a super basic question.

I have this code:

```
mh<-read.csv("mkhz_meta.csv")

msub<-mh[complete.cases(mh[ , 29]),]

msub2 <- subset(msub, Target.Fungal.Phylum!= "a")

png("J_Weighted_2_FungalPhylum.png", width= 800, height=600)
ggplot(aes(x = Target.Fungal.Phylum, fill= Concl..Weighted.nestedness), data =     msub2) + geom_bar(position = "dodge")+
xlab("Target Fungal Phylum")+ ylab("Count")+ ggtitle("Weighted vs. Primer  Specificity")+
theme_bw()+
scale_fill_grey()+
theme(axis.text.x =element_text(hjust = 0.5, size =8, angle= 0), 
    axis.text.y =element_text(size= 10), 
    legend.title=element_blank(), 
    legend.text=element_text(size=10), 
    axis.title.x =element_text(size=10),
    axis.title.y =element_text(size=10))+
theme(panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.major=element_blank(),
    strip.background = element_blank(),
    strip.text.x=element_text(size=14),
    panel.border = element_rect(colour = "black"))
 dev.off()
```

It returns this graph:

[image: Binary vs. Sequencing]

There is one count of non-nested morphotyping, and no count of nested morphotyping - I can't figure out how to have the 'morphotyping' bar be split to reflect this. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: The problem is very likely in your data structure rather than your plot code, but without being able to see your data it's very difficult to know how to help. Provide a subset of your data and I'm sure it'll become clear.

Comment: I'm willing to share the msub2 data frame that's being used, but I don't know how!

Comment: You were right and it was a data frame issue! Have fixed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `tidyr::complete` to add missing counts to your data.

Sample data:

```
mydata <- structure(list(platform = c("454", "454", "454", "454", "454", 
"454", "454", "454", "454", "454", "Morphotyping", "Sanger", 
"Sanger", "Sanger", "Sanger", "Sanger", "Sanger"), is_nested = c("nested", 
"not nested", "nested", "nested", "nested", "nested", "nested", 
"not nested", "nested", "not nested", "not nested", "nested", 
"nested", "nested", "not nested", "nested", "not nested")), .Names = 
c("platform", 
"is_nested"), row.names = c(NA, -17L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), spec = structure(list(cols = structure(list(platform = 
structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), is_nested = structure(list(), class = 
c("collector_character", 
"collector"))), .Names = c("platform", "is_nested")), default = 
structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
"collector"))), .Names = c("cols", "default"), class = "col_spec"))
```

Code to count and plot:

```
library(tidyverse)
mydata %>% 
  count(platform, is_nested) %>% 
  complete(platform, is_nested) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(platform, n)) + 
    geom_col(aes(fill = is_nested), 
             position = position_dodge())
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try adding:

`+ scale_fill_discrete(drop=FALSE) + scale_x_discrete(drop=FALSE)` to your plot command to preserve the empty plot bins.

Comment: I tried this earlier. It returns NULL most of the time, or returns the graph the same as above but in colour.